# Ionic3 Alert with Input Text and Radio Button

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, alert, ionic-native

I am trying to incorporate input text and radio button in one alert dialog box. I have three options and if the user chose the third option, an input text will appear and the user needs to type something.

I've searched on the internet but I can't find something that can help me with this. I hope someone can help me with this.

Here is my code and the sample output.

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Select one?',
        message: "Please select one or enter something",
        inputs: [
          {
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'Option 1',
            value: 'Option 1',
          },
          {
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'Option 2',
            value: 'Option 2',
          },
          {
            type: 'radio',
            label: 'Other Option',
            value: 'Other Option',
          },
          {
            type: 'text',
            placeholder: 'Enter other option',
          }
        ],
        buttons: [
          {
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: (data: any) => {
              console.log(data);
            }
          }
        ]
      });
      alert.present();
```

Here is the current output of my code.

[image]

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: @VelusamyVenkatraman The problem is that, it only shows the three options with a large white space where the input text should be placed. In short, the input text is not showing.

Comment: refer the below [link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-preview-app/blob/master/src/pages/alerts/radio/pages.ts)

Comment: @VelusamyVenkatraman Thanks but according to, this kind of work is not possible. The link you have sent only shows an alert with radio buttons without input text. Anyways, thank you for your effort. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have different `types` of `input` inside ionic **AllertController**.

You should use **Modal Controller** with **formBuilder** and then you can customize form as you want

Comment: Ohhh. That was unfortunate but thanks to your reply. Atleast now I know that I am trying to do something that is impossible. Hehe